# How Do I Repeat Each Lower Case Letter Using Regex in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I want mappings as these:  ABcD --> ABccD,  xyzK --> xxyyzzK, etc.

I can write a loop to do this.  But is there a way to do so with Regex?  I can find all the lower case letters with a character set [a-z].   How do I write the replacing part?

```
$string =~ s/[a-z]/....../g;  # How do I fill in for the ...... ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is with a capturing group and capture variable:

```
$string =~ s/([a-z])/$1$1/g;
```

See [Extracting matches](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches) and [Search and replace](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Search-and-replace) in `perldoc perlretut`.

Comment: Thanks Melpomene.  Exactly what I am looking for.   I didn't know that captured group can be used to replace as well.  Thanks!